# Trigger to insert or update fields when inserting or updating table rows

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I am working with SQL Server 2008. I have created the following table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE DIVISION_DETAILS
(
    DIVISION_CODE NVARCHAR(36),
    DIVISION_ID   NVARCHAR(20),
    DIVISION_NAME NVARCHAR(100),
    CREATED_BY NVARCHAR(100),
    CREATED_DATE DATETIME,
    UPDATED_BY NVARCHAR(100),
    UPDATED_DATE DATETIME,
    ROW_VERSION TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DIV_CODE PRIMARY KEY(DIVISION_CODE)   
);
```

Now i need to create a trigger to insert or update some field automatically when other rows are inserted by application. So far i have created the following trigger but it's not working. can you help me in this regard.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_DIVSION_DETAILS_INS_UPD
ON DIVISION_DETAILS
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN

IF DIVISION_CODE IS NULL 
    THEN DIVISION_CODE=NEW GUID()
END IF

IF ROW_VERSION IS NULL
    THEN ROW_VERSION=NEW DATE()
END IF
END
```

Thanking you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about [Using the inserted and deleted tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

1. Updates and Inserts can affect multiple rows, so your trigger code
   should not assume there is only one to work on.
2. An example of using
   the `inserted` or `deleted` tables could be:

   ```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
       UPDATE DIVISION_DETAILS
          SET UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
         FROM DIVISION_DETAILS DD
   INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON DD.Division_Code = i.Division_Code
   ```
3. Primary Key cannot be null, so you should never have to check for Division_Code being null.
4. If you want a guid as your primary key (not recommended), make the column type `uniqueidentifier`.
5. What you are showing in your trigger code does not need a trigger. It can be done by making the columns NOT NULL and giving them default constraints that will fill them will default values when NULL is supplied on insert:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE DIVISION_DETAILS
   (
     Division_Code uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT(NEWID()),
     /*...*/
     Created_Date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
     Updated_Date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
     Row_Version timestamp NOT NULL
   )
   ```
6. A `timestamp` column automatically generates its values
7. You do not need to use the `nvarchar` type if the strings they contain will not contain extended unicode characters.
8. Find a [good beginning tutorial on Sql Server](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071546383) and database design